# uwsgi+django: unsupported hash type

Tags: python, django, openssl, uwsgi, ubuntu-18.04

When I am deploying my django site to an Ubuntu 18.04 Server,I found that using `python manage.py runserver` works well.But when I use uwsgi to run this django site,a `unsupported hash type`error keeps occuring at the submission of my login form.

Environment: Ubuntu 18.04/anaconda3(use conda to manage virtualenvs)/python3.6/uwsgi2.0.17/django2.0/

error detail:this is where the exception come from:`user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)`

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
unsupported hash type

my uwsgi ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /www/wwwroot/django-xxx/
plungins = python,gevent
socket = 127.0.0.1:8080
module = apps.wsgi:application
gevent-early-monkey-patch = True
gevent-wait-for-hub = True
gevent = 10
workers = 3
master = True
vacuum = True
user = root
logto = /www/wwwroot/django-xxx/uwsgi.log
```

Traceback:

```
File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "./apps/sspanel/views.py" in user_login
  94.             user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in authenticate
  70.             user = _authenticate_with_backend(backend, backend_path, request, credentials)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in _authenticate_with_backend
  115.     return backend.authenticate(*args, **credentials)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/backends.py" in authenticate
  22.             if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in check_password
  111.         return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py" in check_password
  50.     is_correct = hasher.verify(password, encoded)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py" in verify
  256.         encoded_2 = self.encode(password, salt, int(iterations))

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py" in encode
  249.         hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, digest=self.digest)

File "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/crypto.py" in pbkdf2
  85.     return hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(digest().name, password, salt, iterations, dklen)
```

**update:my further explore**
1. change to ubuntu 16.04 without any other changes,not work;
2. change my way installing uwsgi, problem solved:the original way I install uwsgi was to install gcc 4.7 and use it to install uwsgi(installation fails if I directly install uwsgi because gcc version is to high according to my google results).When I try conda to install uwsgi, finally this problem disappears.

Comment: are you using supervisor to run the service?

Comment: Are you sure uwsgi is using your virtualenv ???

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I run `source activate virtualenv_name` in my bash and then `uwsgi -i uwsgi.ini`,I think virtualenv is used this way,right?

Comment: @AnushaPrasanth I have not used supervisor yet,while I am going to,after this error is solved

Comment: @Eubur I have no experience with conda/anaconda, but with vanilla Python this should be `source /path/to/yourvirtualenv/bin/activate`. But re-reading your traceback I can see the libs path start with "/anaconda3/envs/django-sspanel-7" so I can't say for sure...  You say that it "works well" with the dev server, but did you try login in when running the dev server ? If no then there's possibly some package missing, else, well, I have no clue.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I tried login with dev server,works well

Comment: Well... You may want to check whether you're really accessing the same libs when using the dev server (you can just use the django shell and pdb and step thru the `User.check_password()` method and check the modules files along the way).